# Fill asp.net aray from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp code behind to add data to sql using string as following

```
        protected void KbUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rs.Text = elem.Value;
        string[] Ti = new string[] {"Title1", "Title2" };
        string[] De = new string[] { "Description1", "Description2" };
        string[] Dd = new string[] { "2023-03-08", "2023-03-08" };
        string sqlStatment2 = "INSERT INTO [KNtsk] (titl,dscr, due, opnd) values(@titl,@dscr, @due, @opnd)";
        String sqlconn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlconn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStatment2, con))
          {
                con.Open();
                for (int i = 0; i < Ti.Length; i++)
                {
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titl", Ti[i]);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dscr", De[i]);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@due", Dd[i]);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opnd", 1);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmd2.Parameters.Clear();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
    }
```

now i need to fill the Ti , De, Dd arrays using a JavaScript function

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const elements = document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByClassName("lobilist-item-title");
        const descrits = document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByClassName("lobilist-item-description");
        const duedats = document.getElementById("todo").getElementsByClassName("lobilist-item-duedate");
 
    });   
</script>
```

Any idea how to start

Answer (score 0):

JSON Arrays are the way to go. SERIALIZE in the front end and DESERIALIZE on the backend.